# Upload file into Server Root directory

Tags: java, file, file-upload, upload, webserver

I really have a problem while trying to upload a file into my servers root directory. I know that the File-Class cannot handle directorys like `http://localhost:8080/rootdata`.

Please do not tell me not to upload files to the root. I just want to know how to do that.

So is there a way bringing up my files in that root directory via java?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Apache's FTP library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) to browse and retrieve files from your servers filesystem. You can list out all the files in the root directory by using:

```
.listFiles()
```

Example:

```
String hostname = properties.getProperty("FTP_SERVER");
        String user = properties.getProperty("FTP_USER");
        String passwd = properties.getProperty("FTP_PASSWD");
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect(hostname);
        client.login(user, passwd);
        String reply = client.getStatus();
        System.out.println(reply);
        client.enterRemotePassiveMode();
        client.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. But I can't use FTP. Ich want to up- and download the data from the root directory via http-GET and -POST. Is there no other way to work this without ftp?

Comment: There is no other way to get an accurate directory listing.

Comment: Ok thanks. As i cannot use FTP i'm now bringing up the files directly on the servers hdd at a specific, unique directory.